# Does fork() create aliases?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork

When I use `fork()` to create a child process the child is a duplicate of the parent. Would a pointer point to the same thing in each process or does the pointer take a new value in the child. What about an array, or file pointers?

Comment: A pointer in the child holds the same address as the pointer in the parent.  That address it points to holds the same data in both the child and the parent.  If one of the process writes to that value, it will be different in that process, but not in the other.  If one process reads from a FILE *, its internal copy of the FILE * is updated (eg, its position in the file), but not in the other process.  However, anything that modified the underlying file descriptor is seen in both processes.

Comment: So the pointers point to the same value but two different copies of the same value? This is what I am curious about, and as I read your comment it is what you are saying?

Comment: The pointers *have* the same value and what they point to *was* the same at the instant `fork()` returned in each process. What happens after that is up to each process: their address spaces are distinct.

Comment: @EJP so I think my question came from a misunderstanding of the address space. So is a pointer relative to the address space? As in the two pointers are, after the fork, pointing to relatively identical spaces within the duplicate address spaces? Am I understanding this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Would a pointer point to the same thing in each process.**

Yes, all memory is copied including pointers.

**What about an array, or file pointers?**

Yes. In the case of file *descriptors*, it is useful to note that any file descriptors open in the parent, will refer to the same files in the child process.

---

Most (all?) Unix systems use some form of copy-on-write optimisation, meaning that the processes will actually share physical memory until either of them writes the memory. This tends to make fork() a quite cheap operation.

There are corner cases, as noted by Vazquez-Abrams. Perhaps the most important one is that only one thread is forked, the one that invokes the fork() system call.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`fork(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) (emphasis mine):

> The new process, referred to as the child, is an **exact duplicate** of the calling process, referred to as the parent, **except for the following points**:
>
> *
>       The child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)).
>
> *
>       The child's parent process ID is the same as the parent's process ID.
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit its parent's memory locks (mlock(2), mlockall(2)).
>
> *
>       Process resource utilizations (getrusage(2)) and CPU time counters (times(2)) are reset to zero in the child.
>
> *
>       The child's set of pending signals is initially empty (sigpending(2)).
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (semop(2)).
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit record locks from its parent (fcntl(2)).
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit timers from its parent (setitimer(2), alarm(2), timer_create(2)).
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit outstanding asynchronous I/O operations from its parent (aio_read(3), aio_write(3)), nor does it inherit any asynchronous I/O contexts from its parent (see io_setup(2)).
>
> The process attributes in the preceding list are all specified in POSIX.1-2001. The parent and child also differ with respect to the following Linux-specific process attributes:
>
> *
>       The child does not inherit directory change notifications (dnotify) from its parent (see the description of F_NOTIFY in fcntl(2)).
>
> *
>       The prctl(2) PR_SET_PDEATHSIG setting is reset so that the child does not receive a signal when its parent terminates.
>
> *
>       The default timer slack value is set to the parent's current timer slack value. See the description of PR_SET_TIMERSLACK in prctl(2).
>
> *
>       Memory mappings that have been marked with the madvise(2) MADV_DONTFORK flag are not inherited across a fork().
>
> *
>       The termination signal of the child is always SIGCHLD (see clone(2)).
>
> *
>       The port access permission bits set by ioperm(2) are not inherited by the child; the child must turn on any bits that it requires using ioperm(2).
>
> Note the following further points:
>
> *
>       The child process is created with a single thread--the one that called fork(). The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.
>
> *
>       The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).
>
> *
>       The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open message queue descriptors (see mq_overview(7)). Each descriptor in the child refers to the same open message queue description as the corresponding descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share the same flags (mq_flags).
>
> *
>       The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open directory streams (see opendir(3)). POSIX.1-2001 says that the corresponding directory streams in the parent and child may share the directory stream positioning; on Linux/glibc they do not.

Comment: I went straight to man pages but it's just a little hard to decipher.

Comment: "The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent. This means that the two descriptors share open file status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2))."